# The first element of an Object Array is passed as undefined when using JSON.parse

Tags: arrays, object, undefined

I'm using HTML5's local storage to save a small database of user's preferences. To do that I have the following function:

```
function save(UserDB) {
    if (window.localStorage) {  // Only do this if the browser supports it
        localStorage.setObject('UserDataBase', JSON.stringify(UserDB));
    }
```

with

```
Storage.prototype.setObject = function(key, value) {
    this.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(value));
}
```

UserDB is an array of objects similar to this:

[{"uid":"ABC","groupname":"My Group","calendarid":"sdf44d7g3ak5q8ifdrl308hk0@group.calendar.google.com","link":null,"userenable":true,"color":"528800"},{"uid":"CdO","groupname":"CKHO","calendarid":"apkrty45sdfer44fd1mr55dfghfg8@group.calendar.google.com","link":null,"userenable":true,"color":"AB8B00"}]

This seems to work just fine.

Then, when the user loads the site again I'd want to be able to regenerate the object array in a variable from the information stored in the previous session:

```
Storage.prototype.getObject = function(key) {
        var value = JSON.parse(this.getItem(key));
        return JSON.parse(value);
    }
```

This also seems to work. The problem is when I use this last function to actually store the array:

```
    function ApplyUserConfiguration(Data) {

    if (window.localStorage) {  
        var UserDBx = localStorage.getObject('UserDataBase');
        console.log("User Configuraiton found");
        console.log(UserDBx);
        console.log("ActualGetObject");
        console.log(localStorage.getObject('UserDataBase'));
        console.log(UserDBx.length);
        for (var i = 0; i < Data.length; i++){
            for (var j=0; j< 5; j++){
                if(Data[i].uid == UserDBx[j].uid){
                    Data[i].userenable = UserDBx[j].userenable;
                    Data[i].Color = UserDBx[j].color;
                    delete UserDBx[j];
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return Data;
};
```

It turned out that console.log(localStorage.getObject('UserDataBase')); returns the object array correctly but console.log(UserDBx); returns the object array with the first element as "undefined". Any idea why this happens?

Comment: I noticed I was using JSON.stringify twice. I fixed it but the result is the same. I think it's important to point out that the issue seems to be in the following assignment: var UserDBx = localStorage.getObject('UserDataBase'); As the right side returns the correct value but the left doesn't I just don't see the error.

Comment: There were many questions in SO regarding console logging bug on Chrome/Safari. You might want to check them.

Comment: @Jay, yeah it could have been a bug If I explicitly call UserDBx[0] I can access its contents. So far seems to be Chrome's console the one that cannot represent the first element. I was getting a type error during run-time but it turned out to be for another reason. Yet, using console.log(UserDB) still shows the first element as undefined but the rest of the code can use it.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue of seeing undefined element in start. Following was my code:

```
var x;
for (i = 0; i < content.length; i++) {
    x += content[i].name;
console.log(x);
}
```

The reason was undefined x. I was declaring it but I was not assigning it any value. So I just changed var x to **var x=""** and it solved the problem.

**Error free code**

```
var x="";
for (i = 0; i < content.length; i++) {
    x += content[i].name;
console.log(x);
}
```